# Создается ли временая копия объекта, который неявно приводится к другому типу?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

То есть вызовется ли конструктор копирования 4 раза в этом случае :

```
scoped_ptr p(scoped_ptr(scoped_ptr(scoped_ptr(new Object()))));
```

Компилятор видимо оптимизирует этот код и вызывается только раз, а мне важно знать в теории, произойдет ли это или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В теории - да. Но на практике почти все современные компиляторы поддерживают [RVO и NRVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html)

Comment: Добавлю, что стандарт разрешает оптимизатору убирать конструкторы копирования даже если они обладают побочными эффектами. (Это единственное место в стандарте, где оптимизатору разрешается изменение семантики программы.)

То есть теоретически вы никак не можете знать наперёд, вызовутся конструкторы или нет, оптимизатор волен их и убрать, и оставить, на своё усмотрение.

Comment: @Abyx: А что именно происходит в этом случае?

Answer (score 2):

Такой код подпадает под правило *copy elision* (C++11 [class.copy] 12.8/31).

> При определенных условиях, компилятору разрешается убирать копирующее/перемещающее создание объекта класса, даже если у конструктора копирования/перемещения или у деструктора есть побочные эффекты.
>   В этом случае компилятор считает исходный объект пропущенной операции копирования/перемещения и объект-назначение одним и тем же объектом, и разрушение этого объекта происходит когда оба объекта были ли разрушены без оптимизации. Такое удаление операций копирования/перемещения разрешено в следующих случаях (или их комбинации):
>
> - в `T f() { T x; return x; }`,
> - в `T x; throw x;`,
> - **когда временный объект, который не был привязан к ссылке, копируется/перемещается в объект с тем же типом**,
> - в `catch (T x)`.

При этом, даже если конструктор копирования/перемещения не используется, он должен доступен (не удален, не private) как если бы он использовался (C++11 [class.temporary] 12.2/1).

Все современные компиляторы используют это правило, однако стандарт не запрещает существование компилятора, который не делал бы copy elision.