# Надо ли писать return std::move(local_var)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-faq, c++14

Я хочу вернуть из функции большой объект, например переменную `std::string s;`.
Надо ли писать `return std::move(s);`?

Comment: Окей, а в каких случаях _надо_ писать `std::move(x)`?

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Я думал, есть что-то более экзотическое.

Comment: @Abyx Крайне рекомендую посмотреть Мейерса, "Эффективный и современный С++", в разделе 5.3 этот вопрос подробно рассматривается.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Если тип переменной совпадает с типом возвращаемого значения, то **не надо писать** `T t; return std::move(t);`.

Надо писать `T f() { T t; return t; }`, т.к. в `return` переменная `t` считается rvalue.
В стандарте **C++11** написано:

> [`12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy] p32`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#32)
>
> Когда критерии для пропуска копирования/перемещения ([copy elision](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425681/177684), в т.ч. RVO) соблюдены (кроме ограничений на параметры функции), и выражение обозначающее копируемый объект является lvalue, то выбор конструктора происходит так, как если бы это было rvalue.

Одним из случаев пропуска копирования является **NRVO**:

> В `return`, если функция возвращает класс*, и `return` выражение - это имя не-`volatile` объекта с автоматической длительностью хранения (кроме параметра функции или `catch`), и его тип такой же как у типа возврата.

(* примечание: `struct` и `union` - [это тоже типы-классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420635/177684))

**В С++14**, формулировка немного другая, случай с `return` рассматривается отдельно от пропуска копирования (RVO):

> Когда критерии для пропуска копирования/перемещения соблюдены [...] и выражение в `return` это lvalue или [`id-expression`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.general#id-expression) (в т.ч. в скобках) которое обознает объект с автоматической длительностью хранения, объявленный в теле или параметрах функции или лямбда-выражения.

---

Таким образом, начиная с С++11 стандарт гарантирует, что если оптимизатор выключен, и NRVO не будет, то в следующих случаях будет вызван конструктор перемещения, а не копирования:

```
struct T {
  T();
  T(T&&);
  T(const T&);
};

T f() {
  T t;
  return t; // Имя локальной переменной, вызов T::T(T&&)
}

T f() {
  T t;
  return (t); // Имя локальной переменной в скобках, вызов T::T(T&&)
}

T g(T t) {
  return t; // Имя параметра, вызов T::T(T&&)
}
```

Так как всё что делает `std::move(x)` - это преобразует выражение в ссылку на rvalue, то нет никакого смысла писать `T f() { T t; return move(t); }`. (Это также убирает возможность NRVO).

При этом если выражение в `return` не является именем, то автоматическое преобразование в rvalue не будет работать.

```
T f1() {
  struct X { T t; } x;
  return x.t; // Часть объекта, будет вызов T::T(const T&)
              // Надо написать std::move(x.t)
}

T g1(T* pt) {
  return *pt; // Не имя локальной переменной или параметра,
              // Надо написать std::move(*pt)
}
```

Более сложный пример:

```
T h1() {
  T a;
  while (...) {
    T b;
    if (...) {
      return b;  // вызов T::T(T&&)
    }
  }
  return a;  // вызов T::T(T&&)
}

T h2(T a, T b, bool c) {
  return c ? a : b; // Не имя локальной переменной или параметра,
                    // надо написать std::move(с ? a : b)
}
```

**Если тип переменной отличается от типа возвращаемого значения**, то правила выше не действуют, и надо писать `std::move(t)`:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
struct Derived : Base {};

std::unique_ptr<Base> f() {
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> r;
  return std::move(r);  // Нужен явный move, потому что типы разные.
}
```

Comment: Кстати, шланговский анализатор на такие вещи ругается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните подробнее что понимается под "не является именем".

Comment: Про `return (t)` надо бы пояснение. Т.к. элементарная [проверка](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6PA7HsLlTrMB0s5F) показывает вызов конструктора перемещения, а не копирования.

Comment: Фраза `конструктор "перемещения" - это тоже конструктор копирования` не соответствует действительности. Конструктор не может быть одновременно и копирующим, и перемещающим. Принимает `&` значит это конструктор копирования, если `&&`, то это уже конструктор перемещения.

Answer (score 6):

Мейерс в "Современном и эффективном C++" дает совет (раздел 5.3, item 26 в оригинале) НЕ применять `std::move()` к локальным объектам, *которые могут быть объектом оптимизации возвращаемого значения*.

Грубо говоря, если это единственный возвращаемый объект (т.е. возвращаемый на всех путях выполнения) - то не стоит. Но если нет - могут быть разные варианты.

Comment: Да, могут быть, но ведь могут и не быть! Что если не сработает NRVO?  Вот страничка на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx говорит о том, что не будет NRVO если: `Multiple return paths (even if the same named object is returned on all paths) with EH states introduced`

Comment: @sys_dev Долго все расписывать, там не одна страница рассуждений и рассмотрения разных ситуаций. Я просто привел краткое резюме. Не знаю, как на русском, но оригинал в сети точно есть, так что посмотрите..