# Лучший способ вернуть контейнер

Tags: c++, c++14

```
std::vector<int> fun()
{
    std::vector<int> temp;
    for(...)
    {
        // заполняем "temp" чем-либо
    }
    return temp;
}

std::vector<int> testVec = fun();
```

или

```
void fun(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    for(...)
    {
        // заполняем "vec" чем либо
    }
}

std::vector<int> testVec; fun(testVec);
```

Как будет лучше, быстрее и вообще - как правильно вернуть контейнер?

p.s.
Прочитал кучу статей на эту тему на зарубежном "стэке", но там все темы старые, а уже вышел с++14 и 2016 год на дворе, хотелось бы услышать советы и мнения "экспертов" по `с++`, с учетом новых стандартов, в общем поделитесь пожалуйста опытом.

Comment: Учитывая, что современные компиляторы поддерживают [NRVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html) , а с++11 и старше позволяет использовать move сементинку... оба способа будут приблизительно одинаково быстро работать.

Comment: Во втором случае, похоже, не получится "заполнить" константный вектор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь отличия скорее не технические - как быстрее (как вам уже ответили, практически одинаково), а семантические. Например, если в функции вы вносите какие-то элементы в вектор, то в первом варианте вы можете вносить их только в изначально пустой вектор, а во втором варианте - дополнять уже непустой вектор.

Словом, поступайте так, как правильнее с точки зрения логики программы :)

Answer (score 4):

В контексте этого вопроса, в С++14 ничего существенно не поменялось по сравнению с С++11.

Используйте первый вариант, тогда либо оптимизатор сделает NRVO (частный случай *copy elision*), либо произойдет вызов перемещающего конструктора, т.к. в `return temp;` выражение `temp` считается r-value.
Подробнее можно почитать [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491518/177684).