# разница между T const& и T

Tags: c++

Какая разница между типами `T const&` и `T` при возвращении/принятии параметров в функцию, где `T` -- н-ый тип данных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В терминах аргументов функции:**

`T` - означает, что объект передается по значению, т.е. вызывается конструктор копирования объекта (создается новый экземпляр данного типа на стеке). Таким образом, изменение аргумента внутри функции не повлечет на состояние объекта, копию которого мы передали в функцию.

`T&` - означает, что объект передается по ссылке, т.е. без вызова конструктора копирования (прокидывается ссылка на объект, количество памяти выделяемое под которую зависит от разрядности ОС: в 32-битой - *4 байта*, в 64-битной - *8 байт*). Изменение состояния объекта, переданного таким образом в функцию, внутри этой функции повлечет его изменение вне её.

Модификатор `const` означает, что передается константный объект, т.е. объект, который нельзя менять внутри функции.

Если нет необходимости менять объект внутри функции, то объект следует передавать как `const T&` (все, кроме примитивов), примитивы даже в таком случае выгоднее передавать по значению.

*Контрольный пример:*

```
void passByValue(int parm){ parm = 2; }
void passByRef (int& parm){ parm = 2; }

int main()
{
   int parm = 1;

   passByValue(parm);
   cout << boolalpha << (2 == parm); // false

   passByRef(parm);
   cout << boolalpha << (2 == parm); // true
}
```

---

**При возвращении объекта:**

Применимо все тоже, что и для аргументов функции, но существует несколько особенностей.

Если же вы возвращаете ссылку на объект из функции, то будьте уверены в том, что время жизни объекта не истечет за пределами функции.

При возвращании объекта по значению, объект не обязательно будет скопирован, т.к. возможна ситуация с [copy elision](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193700/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83) (частным случаем которой является `RVO/NRVO`), а также применение конструктора/оператора перемещения.

*Контрольный пример:*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int global = 1;

int getByValue()              { return global; }
int& getByRef_valid()         { return global; }
const int& getByRef_notValid(){ return 1; }

int main()
{
   int value = getByValue();
   cout << boolalpha << (1 == global); // true
   value = 2;
   cout << boolalpha << (2 == global); // false

   int& validRef = getByRef_valid();
   cout << boolalpha << (1 == global); // true
   validRef = 2;
   cout << boolalpha << (2 == global); // true

   // переменная notValidRef ссылается на память, которая уже помечена как свободная
   // т.е. может быть перезаписана кем угодно в любой момент времени, что невалидно
   const int& notValidRef = getByRef_notValid();
}
```

Comment: Нет такого понятия как "размер ссылки"

Comment: @alexolut Ссылка по факту является оберткой над указателем, если я напишу "размер указателя", то человек совсем запутается, сейчас как-нибудь тогда переформулирую.

Answer (score 3):

`T const&` или `const T&` - это ссылка на константный объект типа `T` и передача осуществляется по ссылке (нет полного копирования данных). А если используется просто `T`, то осуществляется передача по значению и это требует создания копии объекта. Поэтому при передаче в функцию больших объектов, не требующих модификации, следует использовать передачу по ссылке на константу.
При возвращении также можно использовать ссылку. Но главное при этом не забывать, что объект, ссылка на который возвращается из функции, остается живым после завершения функции. Т.е. нельзя например возвращаться ссылки на локальные объекты функции.

Comment: Зачем тогда передача по значению в принципе?

Comment: для примитивов она быстрее работает, для классов даёт возможность менять данные (иногда достаточно удобно).

Comment: А для возвращения?

Comment: Копия объекта все-таки не всегда создается вроде. Есть RVO/NRVO оптимизации, есть семантика переноса

Comment: @VAfgF обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы это было одно и то же то компилятор не ругался подобным образом:

[image: ошибка]

как видите обе функции одинаковы, только функция ref работает только с постоянными методами переданного ей объекта, которых в классе не объявлено.

что бы убедится в этом раскомментируйте спецификатор **const** в функции **test** класса **T** и ошибки не будет.

[image: ошибки нет]

Это своеобразный механизм защиты